# Saving the results of the CASE statement in a table

Tags: sql, select

I have problem with saving the outcome of the CASE statement to the housing_listing table as a new column. I am not sure how to correctly update the table by adding the new column named commission_price.

```
CREATE TABLE housing_listing (
    transaction_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    number_of_bedrooms INT,
    number_of_bathrooms INT,
    listing_price INT,
    listing_agent TEXT,
    listing_office TEXT,
    date_of_listing DATETIME,
    zip_code INT,
    sold BOOL
)



SELECT transaction_id,number_of_bedrooms, number_of_bathrooms,

CASE
    WHEN listing_price < 100000 THEN listing_price * 1.1
    WHEN listing_price > 100000 AND listing_price < 200000 THEN listing_price * 1.75
    WHEN listing_price > 200000 AND listing_price < 500000 THEN listing_price * 1.6
    WHEN listing_price > 500000 AND listing_price < 1000000 THEN listing_price * 1.5
    WHEN listing_price > 1000000 THEN listing_price * 1.4

END AS Commission_price
FROM housing_listing;
```

Answer (score 0):

The generic method is to use a view:

```
CREATE VIEW v_housing_listing as
    SELECT transaction_id,number_of_bedrooms, number_of_bathrooms,

           (CASE WHEN listing_price < 100000 THEN listing_price * 1.1
                 WHEN listing_price > 100000 AND listing_price < 200000 THEN listing_price * 1.75
                 WHEN listing_price > 200000 AND listing_price < 500000 THEN listing_price * 1.6
                 WHEN listing_price > 500000 AND listing_price < 1000000 THEN listing_price * 1.5
                 WHEN listing_price > 1000000 THEN listing_price * 1.4
            END) AS Commission_price
    FROM housing_listing;
```

This does not put the value in the table; it calculates it when you reference the view.

Many databases also support computed columns.